# Differential of Multi Linear Map

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I’m struggling with how to look at the differential of a multi linear map. The setting:
Let $A: \mathbb{R}^n \times … \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a multi linear map with k entries. I’m asked to compute the differential of $A(x,…,x)$. I’ve tried to look at the case where $n = 1$ and $k = 2$ (and $n=2, k=2$) to look at the small cases and I think I have a general feeling of what happens here, but I’m unsure of what I think happens is actually true…

What I’ve tried: (n=1, k=2)

$A: \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ then sends an element $(x,y)\mapsto A(x,y)$, the derivative is then $dA = (\partial_xA(x,y), \partial_yA(x,y))$ where $\partial_x$ is the partial derivative of $A(x,y)$ to $x$.

When n=2 (or higher), this would result in a matrix, where on the columns the derivative to that component are? But I’m not sure if this is correct…

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand\diff{\mathrm D}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\DD[2]{\frac{\mathrm d#1}{\mathrm d#2}}
$

In this case, it is only confusing to try to think of the differential as a matrix. Instead, think of it as a linear transformation. If $f : V \to W$ for any (normed) vector spaces $V, W$, the differential $\diff f_x$ at $x \in V$ is the "best linear approximation" to $f$; that is $\diff f_x : V \to W$ is a *linear* function. When $V = \R^m$ and $W = \R^n$, you can represent $\diff f_x$ as a real $m\times n$ matrix just like any linear transformation. But in this case $V = \R^n\times\cdots\times\R^n$ and $W = \R$, and viewing $\diff f_x$ as a matrix is possible but not very natural.

Let's consider a function $A : V\times V \to W$; hopefully it will be clear how to generalize to an arbitrary number of parameters. The function $x \mapsto A(x, x)$ can be represented as the composition $A\circ\Delta$ where $\Delta(x) = (x, x)$. Hence by the chain rule
$$
  \diff[A\circ\Delta]_x = \diff A_{\Delta(x)}\circ\diff\Delta_x.
$$
However, $\Delta : V \to V\times V$ is a linear function, and the differential of a linear function at any point is itself; so now we have
$$
  \diff[A\circ\Delta]_x = \diff A_{\Delta(x)}\circ\Delta.
$$
We can write $\Delta = \delta_1 + \delta_2$ where $\delta_1(x) = (x, 0)$ and $\delta _2(x) = (0, x)$, then apply the linearity of $\diff A_{\Delta(x)}$:
$$
  \diff[A\circ\Delta]_x
    = \diff A_{\Delta(x)}\circ(\delta_1 + \delta_2)
    = \diff A_{\Delta(x)}\circ\delta_1 + \diff A_{\Delta(x)}\circ\delta_2.
$$
Applying this on $v \in V$ yields
$$
  \diff[A\circ\Delta]_x(v) = \diff A_{\Delta(x)}(\delta_1(v)) + \diff A_{\Delta(x)}(\delta_2(v)).
$$
Now define $A^1_x(y) = A(y,x)$ and $A^2_x(y) = A(x,y)$. The quantity $\diff A_{\Delta(x)}(\delta_1(v))$ is the directional derivative of $A$ at $(x,x)$ along $\delta_1(v)$; hence
$$\begin{aligned}
  \diff A_{\Delta(x)}(\delta_1(v))
    &= \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{A(\Delta(x) + \epsilon\delta_1(v)) - A(\Delta(x))}\epsilon
\\
    &= \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{A(x+\epsilon v, x) - A(x,x)}\epsilon
\\
    &= \diff[A^1_x]_x(v),
\end{aligned}$$
and similarly $\diff A_{\Delta(x)}(\delta_2(v)) = \diff[A^2_x]_x(v)$. It follows that
$$
  \diff[A\circ\Delta]_x = \diff[A^1_x]_x + \diff[A^2_x]_x.
$$
What this is saying is that to compute $\diff[A\circ\Delta]_x$ it suffices to differentiate with respect to each "slot" of $A$ *separately* and then add the results together. I prefer to write this in much more suggestive notation:
$$
  \diff[A(x,x)] = \dot\diff[A(\dot x, x)] + \dot\diff[A(x,\dot x)],
$$
where the dots should be thought of as specifying *what is being differentiated*. The undotted $x$ should be thought of as being kept constant. If we write $\diff_y$ to specify differentiating with respect to $y$, then another way to write the same thing would be
$$
  \diff[A(x,x)] = \Bigl[\diff_y[A(y,x)] + \diff_y[A(x,y)]\Bigr]_{y=x}.
$$

When $A$ is multilinear, it is of course linear in each argument; but as stated a linear function is its own differential, so
$$
  \diff[A(x,x)](v)
    = \dot\diff[A(\dot x,x)](v) + \dot\diff[A(x,\dot x)](v)
    = A(v,x) + A(x,v).
$$

---

This idea is very powerful, and seems to not be as well-known as it should. For example, this directly implies the product rule: if $f : \R \to \R$ and $g : \R \to \R$, then
$$\begin{aligned}
  \DD{}x[f(x)g(x)]
    &= \DD{}{\dot x}f(\dot x)g(x) + \DD{}{\dot x}f(x)g(\dot x)
\\
    &= \DD fxg(x) + f(x)\DD gx.
\end{aligned}$$
It also extends to gradients since $(v\cdot\nabla)f(x) = \diff f_x(v)$. If $f, g : \R^n \to \R$ then
$$
  \nabla(f(x)g(x)) = \dot\nabla f(\dot x)g(x) + \dot\nabla f(x)g(\dot x) = (\nabla f(x))g(x) + f(x)(\nabla g(x)).
$$
If $f, g : \R^n \to \R^m$ then
$$
  \nabla(f(x)\cdot g(x)) = \dot\nabla(f(\dot x)\cdot g(x)) + \dot\nabla(f(x)\cdot g(\dot x)),
$$
which is something that cannot be expressed well without overdots. When $f = g$ this tells us that
$$
  \nabla(f(x)\cdot f(x)) = 2\dot\nabla(f(\dot x)\cdot f(x)).
$$
More interesting examples come when we consider non-linear functions. For example
$$
  \DD{}x x^x = \DD{}{\dot x}\dot x^x + \DD{}{\dot x}x^{\dot x} = xx^{x-1} + x^x\ln x = x^x(1 + \ln x).
$$